# How do I search for a tabulator in VI?

Tags: vi

I am wondering if there is a possibility to search for a tabulator in `vi`. I am used to vim, but the machine on which I am editing a file doesn't have vim, so please don't suggest to use vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it not just work with /\t? This must have been possible with vi aswell, no?